# cmake c++ boost link

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, linker

I know, there are plenty of different question out there regarding how to link boost libraries with a c++ project. However after hours of trying I still couldn't figure it out.

Here is my problem:

I need a filesystem library. Unluckily I didn't manage to use the new std::filesystem library so I thought let's simply use boost... until now I only needed some header only boost libraries, so I spend a couple of hours to finally manage to build boost (at least I think I have build it) in my directory *C:/boost/stage/lib* I have files called `libboost_filesystem-mgw53-1_64.dll` and so on...

I'm trying to use cmake to link these libraries to my own file, but I really get confused... First of all: in CMAKE should I use "BOOST" "Boost" or "boost"...

At the moment I have a mixture... I use something like:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

SET(BOOST_ROOT "C:/boost")
SET(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:/boost/stage/lib")
find_package(BOOST 1.64.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(SOURCE_FILES list of all my source files)

add_executable(myExecuteable ${SOURCE_FILES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myExecuteable ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY})
```

After hours I figured out that my find_package command only works if I type "BOOST" instead of "Boost"...

But I am not allowed to change:

```
SET(BOOST_ROOT "C:/boost")
```

to

```
SET(Boost_ROOT "C:/boost")
```

I'm using CLION and my Cmake now runs without error messages (finally...)

but if I try to build my program I get this error messages:

```
CMakeFiles\myFolder.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `_static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
C:/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried a lot of different solution provided here in previous questions but unluckily nothing worked so far...

I think I'm missing something obvious

Comment: Looks like you forgot to link the libraries you use.

Comment: should not TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myExecuteable ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY})
do this?

Comment: Why not Boost_LIBRARIES?

Comment: I have also tried TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myExecuteable${Boost_LIBRARIES}) many times... did not help at all...

Comment: You don't need `link_directories()`, btw.

Comment: If you doubt about variables names, consult [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/FindBoost.html). It tells that package to found is named "Boost", and libraries for link are contained in `Boost_LIBRARIES` variable.

Comment: Add `message("Boost SYSTEM ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}")` and `message("Boost LIBRARIES ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")` to find out what those variables are set to.  Do this  right next to your target_link_libraries.

Comment: I have tried the following:

    `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(VieVS_Scheduler_clion ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    message("Boost LIBRARIES ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
    message("Boost SYSTEM ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}")
    message("Boost FILESYSTEM ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}")`

and the output is simply:

    `-- Boost version: 1.64.0
    Boost LIBRARIES 
    Boost SYSTEM 
    Boost FILESYSTEM 
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: ...`

does this mean it has not found any libraries?

Comment: It states which libraries where found. You should grasp some basic CMake  knowledge.